# WPF Data binding listview of images

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to create a ListView that displays an ObservableCollection and regardless of what I do with the ItemTemplate I can't get the image to actually display.  Most of what I've been able to find deals with displaying an image as a property of the collection, but not when it *is* the collection.  I have a feeling I'm just doing something stupid but I'm not able to figure it out on my own.

```
<ListView Visibility="{Binding HasImages, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}}" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Image></Image>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>

private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> _Images = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Images
{
    get { return _Images; }
    set { _Images = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your "Images" property of your ViewModel?

Comment: Shouldn't your <Image></Image> have a source="{binding}"?

Comment: @KevinCook: I tried that and the application enters a break state.

Comment: I tried your code and it's working, I just had to add source="{binding}" as mentioned by @KevinCook. Maybe the problem is in your converter or the way you load the images...

Comment: It's not the converter because if I replace the `<Image/>` with a `<TextBlock/>` I get the appropriate number of TextBlocks.  I will look into how I load the images, however.

Comment: You might need to convert the bitmapimage into an imagesource with a valueconverter,

Comment: @KevinCook BitmapImage is derived from ImageSource. No conversion necessary.

Comment: All you need is `<Image Source="{Binding}"/>` in the DataTemplate. If that doesn't work, there is a problem that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was loading the BitmapImages on a different thread than the UI thread and when the UI thread was trying to gain access it was unable to.

Comment: Then just call Freeze on the BitmapImages to make them cross-thread accessible.